# Extract text from inner tag in Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium

Here is the HTML snippet:

```html
<label class="abc">
  <span class="bcd">Text1</span>
  Text2
</label>
```

How do I just extract `Text2` using selenium script? I know how to extract `Text2` by getting `innerHTML` of "abc" class and then removing `innerHTML` of "bcd" class. But I am just looking for a better way to solve this.

Comment: Which programming language would you like to write in? or would you like in pure xpath?

Comment: Programming languauge: java. Just xpath would also be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Text2')]"));
String test = element.getText();
```

Comment: I don't want to get the element. I want to get the string Text2. If I do getText() of the element found out from above code, I would get Text1 Text2

Comment: This would return Text1 Text2 not just Text2

Answer (score 0):

xpath:

```
//label[@class='abc']/child::text()
```

for Python:

```
returnText = driver.execute_script("return document.evaluate(\"//label[@class='abc']/child::text()\", document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue;")
```

sometimes, there can be spaces and it's evaluated as a string by program, so you should use array:

```
    returnText = []
    returnText = self.driver.execute_script("var iterator = document.evaluate(\"//label[@class='abc']/child::text()\", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null); var arrayXpath = new Array();  var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext(); while (thisNode) {arrayXpath.push(thisNode.textContent);  thisNode = iterator.iterateNext(); }    return arrayXpath;")

    for item in returnText:
        print item
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return Text1 as child of label class is span class? I want to extract text of parent element without including child element's text.

Comment: That xpath i presented in answer return Text2 .

Answer (score -1):

Try This :

```
String text2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class='abc']").Text;
```

Comment: This would return Text1 Text2 not just Text2